# How to calculate the growth function of a hypothesis class?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, vc-dimension

I have this hypothesis class:

H = {ha : R → {0, 1} | a > 0, a ∈ R, where ha(x) = 1−a,a =
{ 1, x ∈ [−a, a]
0, x ̸ ∈ [−a, a] }

I need to compute the growth function for m>= 0. So I think that this function has the VCdim=2 because you can't realize label (1, 0, 1), but I don't know how to calculate the growth function.

Answer (score 0):

lets start from VC=1 - take for example C={1}, you can shatter it! it can can the + labeling by choosing a=0.5 for example and the - labeling by a=1.5.
Now lets look at VC=2 - you can take C={1,2}:

- the labeling +, + can be easily obtained by a=0.5 again
- the labeling -, - can be easily obtained by a=2.5
- the labeling -, + can be easily obtained by a=1.5
- the labeling +, - is not possible! And it's not a coincidence.. for every two positive points, give the rightmost the sign of "-", the other sign of "+" and you cant shatter it. This is of course not enough, you need to show that for every to points in R, but you can without no problem to generalize my explanation to not just two positive points, I will leave that to you :)